# How to change older_than syntax in Gmail filter

Tags: gmail-filters

I'm trying to create a filter in Gmail to delete old mail.

In the part `hasTheWord`, I wrote `label:foo_mail/fuur older_than:20d`
The filter is working but when I tried recording it I got this error message:

```
Confirm creating filter
Filter searches containing "label:", "in:", "is:", date range (e.g. "before:" or "after:") or stars criteria (e.g. "has:yellow-star") are not recommended as they will never match incoming mail. Do you still wish to continue to the next step?
```

and the filter doesn't work any more.

Comment: Filters only act on messages as they're received. A new message will never be older than 0, so you can't use your filter that way.

Comment: @ale I've got message older than 20 days and the're staying in the same label and didin't go in the trash